# Sorting on Same Line Bash

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

Hello I am trying to sort a set of numeric command line arguments and then echo them back out in reverse numeric order on the same line with a space between each. I have this loop:

```
for var in "$@"
do
echo -n "$var "
done | sort -rn
```

However when I added the `-n` to the echo the `sort` command stops working. I am trying to do this without using `printf`. Using the `echo -n` they do not sort and simply print in the order they were entered.

Comment: For what reason wouldn't you want to use `printf`? AFAIK, usually `echo` with arguments isn't portable.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
a=( $@ )
b=( $(printf "%s\n" ${a[@]} | sort -rn) )

printf "%s\n" ${b[@]}
# b is reverse sorted nuemrically now
```

Answer (score 3):

To sort `3 2 1` use `tr ' ' '\n'` to split into lines, pipe it to `sort` and reassemble with `xargs`

```
echo 3 2 1 | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | xargs
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort` is used to sort multiple lines of text. Using the option `-n` of `echo`, you are printing everything in one line.
If you want the output to be sorted, you have to print it in multiple lines :

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo  $var
done | sort -rn
```

If you want the result on only one line you could do :

```
echo $(for var in "$@"; do echo $var; done | sort -rn)
```

Comment: echo -n *doesn't* display the `\n`

Comment: @Jite It's indeed a bit twisted to use the `-e` option in order to thwart the `-n` option.

Comment: Suggest `$(...)` in place of the back-ticks.

Comment: If you simply write `echo $(...)`, everything will be on one line with a newline at the end.  There's no need for the `echo -n $(...)` followed by `echo` to output the newline.  You can also use `printf "%s\n" "$@" | sort -rn` as the command to remove the visible loop (the loop hides inside the `printf` command).

Comment: @HunterMcMillen As I wrote above, echo with options isn't portable. You seem to be right about bash, however in `zsh` as I use: `echo -n Doesn't output the trailing newline`. So adding `echo -n "Bla\n"` outputs the trailing newline. I prefer `printf` for this very reason.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Indeed, I seem to have an issue with simplicity today, thanks for the tip. I'm aware of the `printf` alternative, but the OP doesn't want to use `printf` and *@anubhava* already got this.

Comment: Missed the "don't use `printf`" bit — it always puzzles me when people say "don't use the best possible solution" without giving any ustification.

Answer (score 1):

`man sort` would tell you:

```
   sort - sort lines of text files
```

So you can transform the result into the desired format *after* sorting.

In order to achieve the desired result, you can say:

```
for var in "$@"
do
  echo "$var"
done | sort -rn | paste -sd' '
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to play with the IFS:

```
IFS=$'\n'
set "$*"
IFS=$' \n'
set $(sort -rn <<< "$*")
echo $*
```

This is the same idea but easier to read with the join() function:

```
join() {
    IFS=$1
    shift
    echo "$*"
}

join ' ' $(join $'\n' $* | sort -nr)
```

Comment: This works.  I think you should explain a bit more about why it works, though.  Is it intentional that you set the IFS to two non-standard settings, or was the second setting intended to restore the default?  If the former, why not just `IFS=$' '`; if the latter, you've omitted tab and would do better to save the current value and restore it:  `save="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n';set "$*";IFS=
"$save";set $(sort -rn <<< "$1"); echo $*`.  Since there is only one argument, you could write `$1` instead of `$*` in the `<<<` redirect.  Etc.

Comment: @Jonathan, the two `IFS` settings are intentional. The technique uses `IFS` and echo to join positional parameters with an arbitrary character. When `IFS` is set to `$'\n'` and `set "$*"` is called, the positional parameters are then delimited with newlines. I don't bother saving `$IFS` since it's only scoped to the sub shell:
`bash -c 'IFS="xyz" && printf "$IFS\n"'; printf "$IFS\n"`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's because sort is "line-oriented", so you need every number on a separate line, which is not the case using -n with echo.
You could simply put the sorted numbers back in one line using sed, like that:

```
for var in "$@";
do
    echo "$var ";
done | sort -rn | sed -e ':a;N;s/\n/ /;ba'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Yes, the trouble is because `sort` is line-oriented and the `echo -n` creates a single line.  While the `sed` works, it is a fairly heavy duty option.

Answer (score 1):

No loops required:

```
#!/bin/bash
sorted=( $(sort -rn < <(printf '%s\n' $@)) )
echo ${sorted[@]}
```

Comment: Most concise solution. I prefer this. One `<` is more than needed though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting numbers in single line either comma, or space seperated, use the below

```
 echo "12,12,3,55,567,23,6,9,35,423"|sed -e 's;[ |,];\n;g'|sort -n|xargs|sed -e 's; ;,;g'
```

if your output does not need comma, skip the sed after xargs